# WordPress plugin tag not parsing in <script> block

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, parsing, tags

I'm using the following code in one of my WordPress plugin files:

```
else if($filetype == 'swf'){
print
<<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var embed = '<div>[kml_flashembed movie="$img" /]</div>';
jQuery("#header").prepend(jQuery(embed));
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#$headerID {
background: none;   
}
.flashmovie {
position: absolute;
}
</style>
EOT;}
```

But instead of parsing the `[kml_flashembed]` block, it gets spit out as it is.  I manually put it in my `header.php` file and there it rendered fine, so the problem is in the way the JavaScript is injecting it into the HTML.

Can someone shed some light on what I should change to get the tag to parse instead of getting rendered literally?

(The tag is for the WordPress Kimili Flashembed plugin.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect PHP to replace the `[kml_flashembed movie="$img" /]` if you place it inside of a heredoc block

```
else if($filetype == 'swf'){
print <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var embed = '<div>
EOT;
[kml_flashembed movie="$img" /]
print <<<EOT2
</div>';
jQuery("#header").prepend(jQuery(embed));
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#$headerID {
background: none;   
}
.flashmovie {
position: absolute;
}
</style>
EOT2;}
```

Comment: This makes total sense, but it's not working for me.  I don't see any errors in Firebug, the page just spits out blank.  When I comment out this code the page loads fine, so the problem is here somewhere.  I made sure there aren't any spaces before or after the `EOT;` and `EOT2;` tags.

What else could it be?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Slightly changed the code retry please. Maybe also prepend a print to the `[kml....]` block

Comment: No luck unfortunately.  Without `print` in front of the block it prints a blank page.  With the `print` it spits out the`[kml...]` block literally like it was doing before.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function to expand the shortcode.

Comment: I changed it to the following:
    else if($filetype == 'swf'){
    $content = do_shortcode("[kml_flashembed movie=\"$img\" /]");
    print
    <<<EOT
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert($content);
    jQuery("#$headerID").prepend(jQuery($content));
    });
    </script>

Firebug tells me:
`missing ] after element list`

Any thoughts or suggestions?